# How to get a pixel's value in Avalonia

Tags: c#, .net-5, skiasharp, avaloniaui

I'm just getting started with Avalonia UI, and I need to get a pixel's RGBA value, given its coordinates, from an instance of `Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap`.
In Windows Forms this was straight forward when using `System.Drawing.Bitmap`'s `GetPixel(int x, int y)`, but with Avalonia this seems to be unworthy low-level stuff.

I might be using the wrong image type, but any that can be rendered using `DrawingContext.DrawImage` for your goto immediate mode graphics in Avalonia will do.

The use case is checking whether an icon/sprite was clicked on an opaque pixel in a graphical editor. I'm not looking to use someone's framework for building this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`Bitmap` class represents an arbitrary image that might not be available on the UI thread or CPU-memory.
Consider using `WritableBitmap` class which is always backed by CPU memory and is available for reading/writing at any time. `WritableBitmap.Decode(Stream s)` is available starting from 0.10.5.

Comment: As far as I can see, at best I can get an IntPtr to the pixel buffer, which SKBitmap does not support - or there is a private _bitmap field in the instance returned, at least on Linux. This answer is slightly helpful, but does not provide any useful solution, sorry.

Comment: Is there anyway to create an IImage from SKBitmap? I'm thinking about ditching Avalonia's poor drawing API entirely and render directly with SkiaSharp instead, if that works. At least my rendering will then be fully decoupled from the GUI framework, and can be used with Eto, which also suffers from these apparent shortcomings.

Comment: `WritableBitmap.Lock` returns an `ILockedFramebuffer` instance which can be used to access raw pixel data.

Comment: You can pass the framebuffer pointer to SKBitmap.InstallPixels or to SKSurface.Create, just make sure to destroy those before disposing ILockedFramebuffer instance. That way you can get a software-rendered SKCanvas.

Comment: Thanks, this is beginning to clear things up, although it begs the question what InstallPixels does - does it copy or change the internal pointer of the SKBitmap to the pixels in the locked framebuffer. But I need a persistent reference to the pixels, and locking up to multiple times per frame seems like a performance penalty. With the information so far, I think I'll just store both Bitmap and SKBitmap in memory for separate render and query cases, even with the doubled memory requirements..

Comment: `installPixels` uses `SkMakePixelRefWithProc` internally which keeps a reference to your memory. As of the required persistent storage, you can use a separate SKBitmap instance and blit it into the locked framebuffer once you are ready to pass updated pixels to Avalonia.

Comment: Thank you for all the follow up! It would seem that there is no definite way to have a single pixel buffer for both rendering and querying, but with the added bonus that this paves the way for updating the renderables, I will mark your reply as the answer to my question.